# Snow Leopard: 64-bit replacement for QuickTime API

Tags: 64-bit, quicktime, playback, qtkit, core-video

I'm migrating my movie player to 64-bit.

At present it is capable of decoding movies with both QuickTime API and FFmpeg.

To decode with QuickTime API I create a `QTOpenGLTextureContext` providing a `QTVisualContextRef` and then I obtain a decoded frame of type `CVOpenGLTextureRef` using `QTVisualContextCopyImageForTime`.

Now I want to make my app 64-bit and therefore I can't use QuickTime API anymore because this functions aren't 64-bit.

So I passed to QTKit and I started to decode frames using the method `frameImageAtTime:withAttributes:error:` which gives a decoded frame in various image format. At present I made it to return a `CVOpenGLTextureRef` in order to use all the actual structure of my display routine.
The method actually works and I can get rid of the 32-bit `QTVisualContextRef`.

The problem is that this method is tremendously SLOW!! It's not able to make a realtime playback of an Apple h264 movie trailer. It requires 4 times the time required by the old method to output the `CVOpenGLTextureRef`!

I tried all of the other image type that `frameImageAtTime:withAttributes:error:` can handle in output, without success..it's even slower sometimes..

The given attributes are:

```
[_imageAttr setObject:QTMovieFrameImageTypeCVOpenGLTextureRef forKey:QTMovieFrameImageType];
[_imageAttr setObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:[openGLContext CGLContextObj]] forKey:QTMovieFrameImageOpenGLContext];
[_imageAttr setObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:[openGLPixelFormat CGLPixelFormatObj]] forKey:QTMovieFrameImagePixelFormat];
[_imageAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieFrameImageSessionMode];
[_imageAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieFrameImageHighQuality];
[_imageAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieFrameImageDeinterlaceFields];
```

Which is the real replacement for the QuickTime API is 64-bit? Is there any?

I can't change the main structure of the media player so I must obtain a `CVOpenGLTextureRef` or `CVPixelBufferRef` or `CIImage*`

I hope you can help me!

Comment: I know that I could use AVFoundation but that framework is available only in Lion and I want my app to be compatible even with Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement of QuickTime is AVFoundation. It may not contain all you need at the moment, but this is the future.

Comment: I was afraid of that..
I will move to Lion then..thank you very much ;-)